# Static library built against iOS 8 SDK links with Metal framework

Tags: ios, xcode

When building a static library I write with iOS 8 SDK, the resulting library links with the metal framework:

```
$ otool -arch all -fl <static library>

...
Load command 12
 519      cmd LC_LINKER_OPTION
 520  cmdsize 32
 521    count 2
 522   string #1 -framework
 523   string #2 Metal
...
```

I think this is through UIKit; I don't link against it directly and 'Link with standard libraries' is NO.  This causes problems on Xcode 5.1.1 with iOS 7 as this framework doesn't exist.  Building the static lib with Xcode 5 does not link with metal, but I'd rather build with the latest production release of Xcode, and at some point I'll have to tackle this problem.  How can I build with Xcode 6 and work around this issue for Xcode 5 users?

See also another developer with this issue, he simply used the specific frameworks he required which didn't link with Metal, but I can't do that as I need to link with UIKit:
https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/issues/66
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2457

Comment: Hmmm, how does that work then? A static library is just a bunch of object files containing no link instructions. Is this something new in ios8?

Comment: Not that sure myself, but I believe the object files specify the frameworks they need to be linked against with load commands.  that's what the -l option is, it displays the load commands of the objects.

Comment: OK this is interesting.  Can you tell me how you introduced the `LC_LINKER_OPTION` of `-framework Metal` into the static library?  The reason I ask is, if you can edit that, you can change `-framework` to `-weak_framework` and that may solve your issue.  However reading through the thread you quote, the `LC_LINKER_OPTION` is only supposed to kick-in in order to resolve an undefined symbol, which sounds like weak linking anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dave from card.io here. I.e., the "another developer" referenced above.

Our solution, which should work for you, was to set to `NO` two build settings when building our static library: `CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES` and `CLANG_MODULES_AUTOLINK` (a.k.a `Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)` and `Link Frameworks Automatically`).

Building your library with these module settings disabled will eliminate the `LC_LINKER_OPTION` commands altogether.

The app that uses your library can either enable those modules settings or not. It's the app (and not your library) that must include `UIKit.framework` etc., either automatically via modules or manually as a "linked library".

Comment: Thanks Dave, I'd missed that as your solution, I thought you had just used only the dependent frameworks you required instead of a umbrella framework which also included Metal.  Perhaps I should have referred to you by name too ;)  Cheers!!

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: @DaveGoldman - Where are you setting those flags in your build process (outside of manually setting them in Xcode build settings)? When I try to pass them to the compiler in a podspec (`s.compiler_flags = '-CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES=NO', '-CLANG_MODULES_AUTOLINK=NO'`), they are not recognized.

Comment: @kraftydevil I was setting them manually in Xcode. If you check the Xcode Help panel, you'll see that they correspond to *omitting* the `-fmodules` and `-fmodules-autolink` flags. I'm not sure that a podspec can specify that flags be *omitted*.

Comment: @kraftydevil like this, `s.pod_target_xcconfig = {'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES', 'CLANG_MODULES_AUTOLINK' => 'YES'}`